# Is clustering within cluster a sensible analysis?

Tags: clustering, k-means

Using K-means I have clustered my data into 3 clusters. After further analysis on these clusters I found the following:

- Cluster 1 - Low
- Cluster 2 - Medium
- Cluster 3 - High

Again, I clustered the data within Cluster 3 (High) into 3 clusters.

Now, I was asked how feasible/rational is this analysis? Why not just derive 6 clusters in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The [objective of k-means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering#Description), for a given $k$, is to find a partition $S = S_1 \bigcup \cdots \bigcup S_k$ which is

$$
\arg \min_{S}
\sum_{i = 1}^k
\sum_{x \in S_i}
\left| x - \mu_i \right|^2
. \; (1)
$$

In your second, non-hierarchical, case, $k = 6$. In your first, hierarchical case, you first use $k = 3$, then continue until $k = 6$. This means that you are solving

$$
\arg \min_{S; H(S)}
\sum_{i = 1}^k
\sum_{x \in S_i}
\left| x - \mu_i \right|^2
, \; (2)
$$

where $H(S)$ is a constraint on the hierarchy of the sets. Since a constraint cannot lower the minimum, (2) cannot be lower than (1). If your k-mean applications actually approximate the minimums, then it is unlikely  that (2) will work better than (1) in terms of the minimization objective.

Hierarchical k-means, however, have other advantages, [in terms of execution speed](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/hgifford/projects/k_means.pdf). Note that in this paper, the authors explicitly address how to avoid having the constraint impacting the minimum by too much.